# c++ Import two functions with the same name and parameters from different files

Tags: c++

Let's suppose I have a function named the same and with the same parameters in two different files that I want to import to my main.

```
void foo(int a)
{
    // Some code, this function in file A
}

void foo(int a)
{
    // Some code, this function in file B
}
```

How can I do it?

If it is possible, how could the compiler differentiate between the two functions?

Comment: If they're not in different namespaces then you are violating the One Definition Rule and your program has undefined behaviour

Comment: So should I use something like fileA::foo() and fileB:fooB()?

Comment: yes you should be

Comment: the linker should usually complain ( unless you use some weak symbols somewhere)

Comment: why do you need a function named in the same way in two different files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use namespaces:

#### filea.hpp

```cpp
namespace a {
    inline void foo(int a) {
        // Some code, this function in file A
    }
}
```

#### fileb.hpp

```cpp
namespace b {
    inline void foo(int a) {
        // Some code, this function in file A
    }
}
```

#### main.cpp

```cpp
#include "filea.hpp"
#include "fileb.hpp"
int main() {
    a::foo(1);
    b::foo(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Namespaces are nice, but including `.cpp` files is not.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat is including `.hpp` files better when you have to put the function implementations in them ?

Comment: Yes normally you include `.h` or `.hpp`. But you don't have to put implementations in them, you could have separate headers with declarations. But if you do keep implementation in headers, the functions have to be `inline`.

Comment: I knew the thing with the separate headers already, but that is not practicable in a StackOverflow example, so I will add `inline` to the functions.

Comment: *"not practicable in a StackOverflow example"* Why not?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat because 1. this supposes that the OP has a build toolchain in place that takes care of building an extra object file for every source file and links the object files together. or the OP would have to know how to do it himself. 2. There would 2 more codes in the post, where I think 3 are alŕaedy too much

Answer (score 1):

```
enum class file {
    A, B
};

void foo(int a, file f) {
    if(f == file::A) {
        // Do some stuff for A
    }else{
        // Do some stuff for B
    }
    
}
```

Or just declare them in different `namespace`s